# Boost serialization of an empty std::forward_list

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, forward-list

I'm using Boost 1.59.0 to serialize objects (let's call them Foo) in a `std::forward_list<Foo>`. However, I am unable to do this in cases where `std::forward_list<Foo>` is empty. To demonstrate my problem I have extended the "[Very simple case](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)" from Boost's serialization tutorial.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <forward_list>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/forward_list.hpp>

class Foo
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & a;
        ar & b;
    }

    int a;
    int b;

public:
    Foo()
        : a(-1), b(-1) {}

    Foo(int new_a, int new_b)
        : a(new_a), b(new_b) {}
};


typedef std::forward_list<Foo> TListType;


class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
        ar & my_list;
    }

    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
    TListType my_list;

public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s, TListType new_list) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s), my_list(new_list)
    {}
};


int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    TListType my_list(0);
    // my_list.push_front(Foo(-1,-1));
    const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f, my_list);


    {
        // save data
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << g;
    }


    gps_position newg;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> newg;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with g++ 4.8.3, however running it throws:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::archive::archive_exception'
>
> what():  input stream error
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

If we add one element to the list by uncommenting this line

```
// my_list.push_front(Foo(-1,-1));
```

no exception is thrown and everything seems to work. If I replace `std::forward_list<Foo>` with `std::forward_list<int>` in the above code then the code also works. Additionally, using `std::list<Foo>` or `std::vector<Foo>` also works, so the problem seems to be exclusive to `std::forward_list`.

Question: How can I serialize empty `std::forward_list<Foo>` without inserting dummy Foo objects?

Comment: It seems this issue has been fixed in at least Boost 1.63.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the `ofstream` before reading from the file. Best way, move `ofs` inside the "`// save data`" block:

```
{
    // save data
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << g;
}
```

My guess is, with no data the write is smaller than the ofstream buffer and the file is physically empty/incomplete at the time of reading.

This is a flaw in the "very simple case" example, if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However this did not solve my issue, the same exception is still thrown. I also tried explicitly calling the "close()" method to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in boost (still there in boost 1.67, explanation and patch here: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13563). It's triggered by certain combinations of compiler and default constructors in the list elements.

As a workaround you can serialize a flag indicating if the list is empty. You need to split the serialize function into 'save' and 'load', e.g.:

```
template<typename Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    ar << degrees;
    ar << minutes;
    ar << seconds;

    bool empty = nodes_.empty();  // workaround
    ar << empty;
    if (!empty)
        ar << nodes_;
}


template<typename Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar >> degrees;
    ar >> minutes;
    ar >> seconds;

    bool empty;  // workaround
    ar >> empty;
    if (!empty)
        ar >> my_list;
}

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

Comment: It is not a proper answer so this should be comment below the question. Thanks.